# Unable to convert a ResultSet into a List in Cassandra datastax driver

Tags: scala, cassandra

In the following Cassandra code, I am querying a database and expect multiple values. The function takes and id and should return `Option[List[M]]` where `M` is my model. I have a function `rowToModel(row: Row): MyModel` which could take a `row` from `ResultSet` and convert it into instance of my model.

My issue is that the `List` I am returning is always empty even though `ResultSet` has data. I checked it by adding debug prints in `rowToModel`

```
def getRowsByPartitionKeyId(id:I):Option[List[M]] = {
val whereClause = whereConditions(tablename, id);

val resultSet = session.execute(whereClause) //resultSet is an iterator
val it = resultSet.iterator();
val resultList:List[M] = List();
if(it.hasNext){

  while(it.hasNext) {
    val item:M = rowToModel(it.next())
    resultList.:+(item)
  }
  Some(resultList) //THIS IS ALWAYS List()
} 
else
  None
}
```

I suspect that as `resultList` is a `val`, its value is not getting changed in the `while` loop. I probably should use `yield` or something else but I don't know what and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by converting `Java` `Iterator` to `Scala` and then using `toList`

```
 import collection.JavaConverters._

val it = resultSet.iterator();

if(it.hasNext){

  val resultSetAsList:List[Row] = asScalaIterator(it).toList
  val resultSetAsModelList = resultSetAsList.map((row:Row) => rowToModel(row))
  Some(resultSetAsModelList)
```